# Confused about Python sub-sub-packages

Tags: python, module, package

as the title says, I am confused about sub-subpackages. My package structure is the following:

```
draw \
    __init__.py

    base \
        __init__.py
        utils.py
        events.py
        master.py
        basegui.py
```

Now, the first line of `draw.base.events` is the following:

```
import draw.base.utils as _utils
```

And the first line of `draw.base` is:

```
from draw.base.events import Event, RenderEvent, InputEvent, MouseEvent, KeyboardEvent
```

Just checking the code for SyntaxErrors with IDLE:

```
import draw.base as base
```

gives the following `AttributeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import draw.base
  File "Z:\Eigene Dateien\Eigene Dokumente\Python\draw\base\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import draw.base.events as events
  File "Z:\Eigene Dateien\Eigene Dokumente\Python\draw\base\events.py", line 10, in <module>
    import draw.base.utils  as _utils
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'base'
```

Can someone explain to me whats the issue ?

Comment: Is `draw.base` a separate file? Otherwise, I don't understand what you mean by "the first line of `draw.base` is...".

Comment: I believe he meant the first line of `draw/base/__init__.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to import `draw.base.utils` in `draw.base.events` Python needs to import `draw.base` which is being imported now so there is no `draw.base` yet. You can replace `import draw.base.utils` with `import utils` (you can also use something like `from ..base import utils` in 2.7, 3.x or with `from __future__ import absolute_import`) in `draw.base.events` to break the circle.

Comment: Using `import draw.base <<newline>> import draw.base.utils` doesn't work either, also using `import .utils` does not work (including __future__ import). (Python 2.7)

Comment: Do i have to import `draw.base` in `draw\__init__.py` ?

Comment: `import draw.base` won't work anyway. `import .utils` is a syntax error, it can only be used as `from ..base import utils`.

Comment: I wanted to avoid `from xx import yy` as I like the other syntax more. But there is no way around, I see. ;)